# Delay until objects get visible

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are creating buckets in plannerPlans with the Microsoft Graph API with POST request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/buckets
```

and this request body:

```
{ planId: <planId>, name: '<new bucket name>', orderHint: ' !' }
```

Previously with the beta API, such requests finished very fast and the created bucket was visible immediately in the browser and in the API thru this request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/<planid>/buckets
```

Now with the released API, the request finishes similar fast, but it takes up to **10 seconds** until the newly created bucket is visible in Web and in the API.

The only work-around we see so far is to poll on the above mentioned GET request every other second until the newly created bucket is visible, but that's tedious!

Is there any other option to synchronize such requests, so we can be sure that a newly created bucket exists and is visible to the Graph API, before we continue with our script?

We recognize similar delays when creating groups/plans, any options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for synchronous processing today. However, POST requests return the full data of the created resource, including the etag value, so you shouldn't need to do a read after creation. In other words, all the data you'd receive from the GET request is already returned as a response to the POST request. The returned information can be used for further updates on the resource or can be used with related resources (e.g. you can create tasks and put them in this bucket, even before you are able to read the bucket back).

This also applies to PATCH requests, if "**prefer**" header is set to "**return=representation**".

Comment: ok, then we stay with our current implementation to retry it every second until we can successfully read/write the data. After 10 attempts we give up. So far we never needed more than one retry, so that's an acceptable solution in our specific case.